# XmlPullParser replace text in tags

Tags: java, android

e.g. Client:  xmlpullparser extracts "Client: " successfully but I want to replace "Client: " with "HELLO WORLD" and write it into the xml file i just read from. How do i do this?

```
    public static ArrayList<String> extract_xml (String path) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> xml_results = new ArrayList<String>();

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

    InputStream open_xml = new FileInputStream(path);
    xpp.setInput(open_xml, null);

    int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
    String currentTag = null;
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            currentTag = xpp.getName();
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            if("t".equals(currentTag) && xpp.getText().equals("Client: ")) {//tag to search for
                xml_results.add(xpp.getText());

            }
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
    }
   return xml_results;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the DOM model instead? Using the `Document` you should be able to modify the dom and write it back easily.

See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/419185/Simple-XML-manipulation-techniques-within-Android) for an example.